# Kак написать программу на Android на C#?

Tags: android, c#

Самый простой и эффективный способ, пожалуйста. Нужно создать простое приложение для мобильного телефона. Минимум установки и минимум настройки. Сразу отпишусь что это не игры, а что то типа таймера с записной книжкой + подключение к сети.

Comment: http://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/

Answer (score 11):

[Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) позволяет писать на C# не только под Android, но и IOS с WindowsPhone, причем довольно таки качественно, учитывая кроссплатформенную природу субьекта.

Comment: он платный? мне бы бесплатно. элементарное приложение написать

Comment: @Lutsa считай бесплатный
https://store.xamarin.com/

Comment: VS2015 имеет в своем составе Xamarin